# Adiabatic Transformations and ideal gas relations

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

For an adiabatic transformation of an ideal gas I know that from equation,

$C_v=\frac{dU}{dT}$

I can rewrite it using the relations,

$dU=dQ-dW$

which can give us

$dU=-pdV$

to rewrite the first equation as,

$C_vdT=-PdV$

I know that $C_v$ is the specific heat for when the volume is held constant, so why is it that we can relate it to the change in volume $dV$? I understand how I get there mathematically but conceptually I dont understand.

Comment: For an ideal gas, Cv does not depend on V.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense thank you